# handlebars adding manipulated ajax data to template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, handlebars.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use manipulated data from a returned ajax request with Handlebars.

In my database I have the data stored as an object such as:

```
{"1 year":"$4.95", "2 years":"$3.95"}
```

Now I want to be able to use the data as key/value pairs, so I have tried the following.

```
Compare.prototype.show = function(data) {
        // data returned from ajax request

    $.each(data, function (index, dataItem) {
       // grabbing the returned pricing_term data for manipulation

        var priceData = dataItem.pricing_term;

        var priceObj = JSON.parse(priceData);

        $.each(priceObj, function(term, pricing) {
           // How can I access this data on my handlebars template?
        });

    });

    var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#compareResultsTemplate').html() );

    $('div.results-container').append(template(data));
}
```

I have retrieved the key/value pairs (is there a cleaner way to do this?), but now I'm not sure how to use it in my handlebars template. I have tried to use the key/value pairs in my handlebars template, but it returns nothing. Here is what I tried

```
 <div class="result">
    {{#each this}}

    <div class="planTerm">
        {{term}}
    </div>
    <div class="planPrice">
        {{pricing}}
    </div>

    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the template you have, the value for `data` that you pass to `template` needs to look like this:

```
var data = [
    { "term": "1 year", "pricing": "$4.95" }, 
    { "term": "2 years", "pricing": "$3.95" }
];
```

Using the `$.each` loop on `priceObj`, you could assemble your data array like this:

```
var data = [];
$.each(priceObj, function (term, pricing) {
    data.push({ "term": term, "pricing": pricing });
});
```